# React useEffect doesn't trigger sometimes when I update my list as its dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const mylist = [1,2,3,4,5];
useEffect(() => {
console.log(mylist)
}, [mylist])
```

This is part of my code. `useEffect` doesn't trigger when I append a new element to *mylist*, but it does when I delete an element.

How do I fix it so that it triggers when I append new elements to *mylist*

I have a button doing `onClick(e => mylist.push(e))`
and another one `onClick(e => mylist.remove(e))`

Comment: Show how you are appending and deleting to give some context

Answer (score 4):

The array that you're creating isn't being stored in state, so every render a new array is being created. The solution is to use react state:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [myList, setMyList] = useState([0,1,2,3,4])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(myList)
  }, [myList])

  return (
   <div>
     {JSON.stringify(myList)}
     <button onClick={() => setMyList([...myList, myList.length])}>Add</button>
   </div>);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't make a comment on @Gerard's answer until I have more reputation points. I want to add that make sure you pass an arrow function to setMyList as shown:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [myList, setMyList] = useState([0,1,2,3,4])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(myList)
  }, [myList])

  return (
   <div>
     {JSON.stringify(myList)}
     <button onClick={() => setMyList(prevList => [...prevList, prevList.length])}>Add</button>
   </div>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I change the dependency to `mylist.toString()`
I thought useEffect does deep comparison on the second parameter

Comment: Right, if you converted your values to strings, it will work. String equality is much simpler than Array equality, as the arrays you're comparing are different objects even if their values are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the `length`  of the `array` so if the `array` size changes the effect will be excecuted:

```
useEffect(() => {
  //Your effect  
}, [mylist.length])
```

Comment: It may be possible to add and remove an item in the same update. This wouldn't work in that case.

Answer (score -1):

useEffect using strict comparison, but an array always comes up as false, so [1] === [1] is false and [1] === [1, 2] is still false.

It likely only runs on first render, that is why it's not updating it when you add or remove from list. Try putting the length of the array as a dependancy and it'll work as you intend it to.

So,

```
useEffect(() => {
//stuff on myList
}, [myList.length])
```

So if you add something to it, it'll be comparing integer to integer